# Nodejs mongoose mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to update array field if array and left only 3 values in array.
For example, if have documents 
`users = [
{name: 'aaaaaa', tags: ['a','b','c','d']},
{name: 'bbbbbb', tags: ['a2','b2','c2','d2', e2]},
]` 
In result, i want to receive 
`users = [
{name: 'aaaaaa', tags: ['a','b','c']},
{name: 'bbbbbb', tags: ['a2','b2','c2']},
]`
Or, if i can, i want to check array length and update array in one request. I want to pushing to array values, and if array more then 3, just remove first element, and all actions must be in one request cause JS is async and i can not do this using js code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the User mongoose model.
So to update documents the way you want, you have to update each document.

```
Users.find({},(err, users)=>{
    users.forEach(user=>{
        if(user.tags.length > 3){
            user.tags.splice(0,1); //Removes first element from array
            user.save(err=>{ if(err) console.log(err); }); //Saves modified document
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is wrong way. If my server receive two requests at the same time, first request select user's data and second request select user's data, then first request change data and save them and second request change data and when it will be saving it, second request replace data, that was changed by first request

Comment: You didn't properly describe your issue. You asked how to update the array of documents from mongo in one request. The code above solves the issue. If you want to update db after request is received, the collection will be updated each time, when request will be received. I can only recommend you to sort out in architecture and realization